# Django Fileupload error

Tags: python, django, file, upload

```
class BoardFiles(models.Model):
    index = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='static-assets/')

<form method="post" action="/board/update/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="id_file" multiple/>
</form>

@csrf_exempt
    def board_update(request):
        for file in request.FILES.getlist('file'):
            fl =  BoardFiles (index=request.POST['id'],
                       file=file)
            fl.save()
```

But, When I upload files, There are no datas on BoardFiles table.
What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the built in Django tag [url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#url) so in your form it should look like action="{% url 'update' %}"